# File version maintainence via PHP FTP?

Tags: php, ftp, version

Currently I'm working on a "plugin" that will be installed on many different sites and I was wondering on the best way for me to maintain the file version of this "plugin".

Here's what I was thinking. Have a "master copy" of the plugin on a server, then connect via FTP to the target sites and upload the copy to their site overwriting whatever files they may have.

I was wondering the best way to go about this.

The "plugin" will have many different folders and files so transferring one file at a time will be too tedious. Is there a way to copy an entire folder over at a time?

Or even better, is there a way to recurse through the folders and checking for file difference before uploading the new file? This is to make sure we are uploading a new file and not just the same one.

Comment: is this for an open source project? are you using source version control like git or subversion?

Comment: This is a closed sourced private project. Essentially I'm going to have a main site and sell "sub-sites" that will each use this plugin, but I want to be able to make changes to the plugin and not have to sift through hundreds of sites to update the plugin.

Comment: Why push files to sites via FTP, when they can simply pull the files themselves via HTTP?  Pulling is generally easier than pushing -- it requires only a single server to run.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a source version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 0):

For transferring multiple files, you could use PHP's [zlib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) functions. Then you could have the clients extract the archive when it arrives.